# Notation for similar/related functions

Tags: notation

Suppose I have two functions:

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$

These functions are similar -- meaning, they are variations of the same general thing. I want to express to the reader that they are similar/related.

I tried superscripts:

$f^{variation1}(x)$ and $f^{variation2}(x)$

But that seems unwieldy. What is best practice?

Comment: Can you pin down what the difference is mathematically? Are they parametrized versions of some more general function? Then you could just add arguments. Or you could throw them in an equivalence class if the difference is not important and use tilde to say they are similar. I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, personally. Other alternatives are $f^{(1)}(x)$ and $f^{(2)}(x)$ or $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$, but these could both be confused with differentiation if you're dealing with any calculus.